# Why is my database variable undefined in this php script I'm calling from Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I click on `.deletePost` I get the following errors. It seems like `$mysqli` is `undefined`, but I use it in a similar php script in the same way and it doesn't have this error so I am confused as to whats going on. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

**errors:**

`Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\wamp\www\NightOwlSoftware\scripts\post_action.php on line 16`

`Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\NightOwlSoftware\scripts\post_action.php on line 16`

**post_action.php**

```
<?php

include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
echo "<div>Hello World</div>";
echo "<div>Hello World</div>";
echo "<div>Hello World</div>";
echo "<div>Hello World</div>";
if($_GET['action'] == "deletePost")
        deletePost($_GET['postTitle']);
function deletePost($title){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE Title = '$title'";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
}
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.  
}
?>
```

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // username
$password="********"; // password
$dbname="nightowl"; // Database name
$tblname="blog"; // Table name
$mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$dbname");
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.deletePost').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"scripts/post_action.php",
        data: {action: "deletePost",  postTitle: $(this).siblings("h3.blog").text()},
        success: function(response){
            $("body").html(response);
            alert('DELETED SUCCESSFULLY');
            }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Btw, where is this `$mysqli` variable defined in your post_action.php script ?

Comment: Well I include dbconnect and functions.php and I use sec_session_start() which I thought defined it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: The first parameter of `mysqli_query()` should be a link identifier, returned from mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init(). ref:http://us1.php.net/mysqli_query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you're calling $mysqli inside a scope where it's not defined as $mysqli is not global. You will have to pass it as an argument of deletePost function. For example:

```
function deletePost($title, $mysqli){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE Title = '$title'";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question instead of down voting me... I'm obviously trying to understand and you can't do research on something when you're not sure of the question.

Comment: `$mysqli` *is* global, that's the problem. You mean to say it's not *superglobal*. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `mysql_select_db()` and `mysql_connect()` because you already declared it.